# What is wrong with this piece of C++ code?

Tags: c++

I have just started programming in C++ and I was playing around with templates.

The following code fails at run time and I have no clue why. (Please note that it is just a sample code and not used in production)

```
 bool maxCompare(string* s1,string* s2){
    cout<<*s1<<endl;
    cout<<*s2<<endl;    
    return true; //If I comment this line and instead use the line below, it works fine.
    //return *s1 < *s2;
}

int main()
{
    string* s1=new string("Hello");
    string* s2=new string("Hi");
    string *s3= max(s1,s2,maxCompare);
}
```

Comment: `g++ -g -Wall source.cpp` and than `gdb ./a.out` and in gdb: `run` and than `bt` when it fails... Or if you're geeky enough: `start; s; s; s; ;s...` :)

Comment: Which compiler are you using? You cannot do this on MSVC in debug mode

Comment: What is the error message? BTW, I would expect the code to work if you comment the indicated line and use the line below

Comment: Sorry, I left out some details in my original question. I am invoking the max() function in STL and I am using Microsoft VC++ compiler. (VS 2010). The code works fine in release mode. In debug mode, I get an error "Debug assertion failed. Invalid operator < "

Comment: There's not really enough in that snippet to tell what might be going on, and you haven't supplied the error message the compiler produces. I'd guess you have your own string class and it hasn't got an operator< defined. But that's a wild guess.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Mike Seymour and Paul23 nailed the problem correctly. Thanks:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operator is invalid. In stl's implementation of max there is an assertion for the comparison function that it can never happen that both `a < b` and `b < a` are true. If you come to think a bit this should never really happen. Your second function does not have this problem so it works. Also check that if you return false it will work.

Comment: @Prashanth: If neither `a < b` nor `b < a`, than `a` and `b` are considered equal. So if you return `false`, you've just made all strings equal. Which is useless but valid definition.

Answer (score 4):

It probably fails because of some safety checks (by vs studio)..

For comparing things the C++ standard requires that comparing works correctly: if `a < b` yields true, than `b < a` must yield false.

Visual studio does some internal checks (when building for debugging) to check if this is the case. However your comparison will always yield true, so it can't work correctly.

Other than that: please describe the exact problem, and show us what you have included. "string" isn't something from itself - std::string is defined by the standard, you probably have `using namespace std` somewhere which removes the need to write std:: in front of strings. - However this is considered bad and should just be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously function always returning `true` is not a strict weak ordering. Therefore the behaviour of `max` is not defined and the compiler may choose to do whatever it wants. For example it could make daemons fly out of your nose.

If you use the later return value, it is a strict weak ordering, so the code works as expected.

On a side note, *unlearn using `string*`*. In C++, you should rarely pass things by pointer (prefer (usually constant) reference instead), even more rarely use `new` and almost never use `delete` (that's what `std::auto_ptr` (C++03) or `std::unique_ptr` (C++11) are for). In particular case of string (and most other STL containers), you should be using it by value and only for passing to functions optimize to const references.

Answer (score 0):

This code works just fine with my gdb(7.1) and g++(4.4.3)
could you post your g++ and gdb version?
If you execute your binary on an different system than your compile system
try to force static linking and retest.
Also please post the error you get while debugging.
BTw : You also can use the
`s1 > s2`
lib operator which works perfectly fine.

```
    g++ -g -Wall source.cpp -static
```